# Progress 4GL: Buffer handle attribute for all fields

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, dynamicquery

I am fairly new to Progress and even newer to handles so apologies if I have missed anything obvious, I've looked online but am yet to find what I'm looking for.

I am running a dynamic query similar to the below, in this example after then query is run, the "age" field of the corrresponding record is displayed on screen, I understand how this is done from the buffer-field attribute-method, but my question is how do I display the entire record, is there an equivalent attribute method, or have I misunderstood something crucial?. Thank you for your time.    :

```
def var tbl as character no-undo.
def var fld as character no-undo.
def var qh as handle no-undo.
def var bh as handle no-undo.
def var fh as handle no-undo.

assign tbl = "customer".
assign fld = "age".
create buffer bh for table tbl.
create query qh.
qh:set-buffers( bh ).
qh:query-prepare( "for each " + tbl + " where name = 'tom'" ).
qh:query-open.

do transaction:
    qh:get-first( no-lock ).
    fh = bh:buffer-field( fld ).
    display fh:buffer-value.
end.

delete object bh.
delete object qh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "easy" way to display the entire record in one statement the way you can with a static "DISPLAY table-name" statement. You can get the count of fields (buffer-handle:NUM-FIELDS) and then step through the individual fields and display their values using

```
DO i = 1 to bh:NUM-FIELDS: 
     DISPLAY bh:BUFFER-FIELD(i):BUFFER-VALUE WITH DOWN.
     DOWN.
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create query qh.
qh:set-buffers( bh ).
qh:query-prepare( "for each " + tbl + " where name = 'tom'" ).
qh:query-open.
qh:GET-FIRST().
DO while qh:QUERY-OFF-END = False:  
   DO i = 1 TO bh:NUM-FIELDS:
      display bh:BUFFER-FIELD (i):NAME STRING(bh:BUFFER-FIELD(i):BUFFER-VALUE) with down.
      down.
   END. 
   qh:GET-NEXT ().
END.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).